# Поддержка angular7 в ie9

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript, internet-explorer, angular

Необходимо обеспечить поддержку angular7 в ie9. По найденным советам уже подключил всевозможные полифиллы

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es6/typed';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'promise-polyfill/src/polyfill';
import 'console-polyfill';
import 'blob-polyfill';
/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

Но всё равно в ie9 практически не работает. Отображается только часть компонентов, роутинг не работает и т. д.. Есть ли какой-то способ обеспечить достойную поддержку?

Comment: вопрос у вас слегка странный... `Но всё равно в ie9 практически не работает` - что не работает? `Отображается только часть компонентов, роутинг не работает и т. д` - почему? что пишет консоль? я например не вижу смысла от полифилов, которые вы привели

Comment: При загрузке в консоль ничего не выдается, просто отображается лишь часть из того, что должно отображаться (что очень странно). При клике по ссылкам на роуты выдаются такие ошибки
ERROR TypeError: Объект не поддерживает свойство или метод "pushState"
ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]

Comment: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

Comment: `pushState` действительно не поддерживается в IE9, вам нужно искать какой-то полифил. Страшно представить что у вас за проект такой где требуют поддержку IE9 :D